# How can I define programming struct variables as mathematical notation?

Tags: notation, mathematical-analysis

My purpose is to write a journal paper related to shared computing more abstractly (simply **cost model**) and I need to refer to these variables in both equation and its corresponding pseudocode.

I want define variables of a `struct` as mathematical notation. I get lost in between programming and mathematical concept. I'm trying to pin down the convention where property $a$ of object $b$, I am not sure which one is correct way to use: $a.b$ , $a_b$ , $a(b)$.

---

Assume I have following `structs` in C. I want to define those variables and use them in both equation and its corresponding pseudocode.

```
struct Jobs {  
   int start_time;   
   int completion_time;
   int run_time;       
   int requested_cpu;   
}                       

struct Providers {
    int fee;
    int available_cpu;
}

int main( ) {
   struct Jobs j;    
   struct Providers p;   
}
```

---

The way I define them is: `j.<variable_name>`, `p.<variable_name>`, which is more likely a programming approach. Is it an appected notaition? Here should I define $j$ and $p$ as well?

Example:

```
Symbol   |  Meaning
-------------------------------------------------------
$j$       | Job object 
$j.t_s$   | Start time of the job.
$j.t_c$   | Completion time of the job
$j.X^{t}$ | Execution time of the job
$j.R$     | Number of CPU cores requested for job
$p$       | Provider object
$p.F$     | Fee of provider with per CPUminute
$p.A$     | Number of available CPU cores on provider
...
```

Equation example:

$$C(j, p) =\underbrace{p.F \times j.R \times j.X^{t}}_{computation\ cost}$$

The way I refer them in a pseudocode:

```tex
if p.A = 0 then
    C = p.F * j.R * j.X^{t}
fi

if j.t_s < j.t_c then
    ....
fi
```

How can I define programming struct variables into mathematical notation concept? Any recommendation or helpful guide as books would be appreciated.

Comment: Usually a subscript is better-looking, so I would usually denote it by $obj_{field}$

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/51094/5038, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4381060/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/149204/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  I notice you got comments on multiple sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of using pseudocode is clear and is very commonly used.

Remember that the goal of pseudocode is to be clear.  It is not to provide mathematical formalism.  It is intended for a human audience, not for a computer.  As long as most readers will understand what you mean, it is fine.

As a stylistic matter, I don't like `j.X^{t}`; I would just use `j.X`.  (As it stands, people might wonder whether `t` is a variable and this is representing exponentiation or indexing or something.  They won't imagine that `X^{t}` is the name of a field.)  Similarly, I don't like `j.t_s` so much; I would like `j.t` or `j.s` or `j.ts` better.

Comment: How could I apply `j.X` use case when there is nested structs? Please see: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/how-can-i-define-nested-structs-as-mathematical-notation?noredirect=1#comment313576_149621

Answer (score 2):

From  the perspective of functional programming languages like C, structs are just records - a composite type. You may consider algebraic data types as mentioned by @deepak Gupta.

If you want to be more precise, you might want to delve into abstraction like in OOPS. Structs are essentiallyba simpler form if abstraction than a class. Object calculus as proposed by Abadi, Cardelli might be what you are looking for.
The book is not free but some of their course slides are - see e.g. page 49 onwards here
http://lucacardelli.name/Talks/1997-06%20A%20Theory%20of%20Object%20(ECOOP%20Tutorial).pdf