# How can I define nested structs as mathematical notation?

Tags: notation, mathematical-analysis

My purpose is to write a academic paper related to shared computing more abstractly and I need to refer to these variables in both equation and its corresponding pseudocode.

In my pseudocode I have nested `structs`, where it makes it harder to represent them in simplified equations.

---

Assume I have following nested structs in `C`. `Jobs` struct uses `Fees` struct. `Fees` could have additinal stuct inside and so on.

```
struct Fees {
    int cpu;
    int data;
}

struct Jobs {
   struct Fees F;
   int start_time;
   int completion_time;
   int run_time;
   int requested_cpu;
}

int main( ) {
   struct Jobs j;
   j.F.cpu = 20
   j.F.data = 10

   nproc = 4
   run_time = 60
   cost = j.F.cpu * nproc * run_time
   // ... //
}
```

In `C` code, I can access/represent the variable using `j.F.cpu`. Could I use same way as mathematical notation? or should I do `subscript` for the objects' variables, such as $j.F_{cpu}$? or should I do completely different approach?

Assume $j$ is a `Job object`. Alternative to $j.F.cpu$, I come up following subscripts examples:

- $j.F^{cpu}$ == `$j.F^{cpu}$`
- $j.F_{cpu}$ == `$j.F_{cpu}$`
- $j_{F_{cpu}}$ == `$j_{F_{cpu}}$`
- $j_{F^{cpu}}$ == `$j_{F^{cpu}}$`
- $j_{F.{cpu}}$ == `$j_{F.{cpu}}$`

Related: [How can I define programming struct variables as mathematical notation?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/149204/how-can-i-define-programming-struct-variables-as-mathematical-notation)

I am using following approach if there is not nested structs:

> As a stylistic matter, I don't like `j.X^{t}`; I would just use `j.X`

Comment: I don't see a real need to reflect the structs at all in the mathematical explanation. By the way, Fees is used only once, so needn't even exist.

Comment: I show fee usage once for a basic example, in my real implementation it is used more than once.